# Why do I get only a subset of elements in a column instead of the whole column in python?

Tags: python, csv, bioinformatics

I am having a problem with my code.

```
for f in allCassetteFiles:
        mypath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        file_path = mypath + '/cassette_output_test/%s'%f

        with open('%s' %file_path,'r') as cassetteFile:
            lines = pd.read_csv(cassetteFile)
            geneStart = lines['start']
```

What I want to do is to store at geneStart list the **whole column** named 'start' from the CSV file  and when I compile the code it **gives me only a subset of elements** starting from the middle of the column till the end. Can you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: There might be more than one column naming start. Pandas will rename the other columns (into "start.1", "start.2", ...), so something need to be done to findout the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Pandas, it's waaaay better than doing all this by yourself. Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

myfile = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
print(myfile["mycolname"].tolist())
```

Generally pandas works great with csv and xlsx files and provides humongous amount of methods to look for/filter/merge/insert/remove data :)

Comment: I get the same result even using your method

Comment: Maybe csv is wrongly formatted? Try to load it into excel and then split text to columns (in "data") to see if it looks fine.